# Countdownjs how to show 0 units

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, countdownjs.js

I am using the JS library CountdownJS. I am wanting to return a zero value for each of the time units when applicable. Currently when the value is 0 the unit just doesn't show.

Here's what I want to see:

[image]

Here's what I currently see:

[image]

Anyone familiar with the library know where in the source I would look to update this?

Ref: http://countdownjs.org/readme.html

Comment: Do you *need* to use a library for this? A countdown is really simple to implement (one function).

Comment: Nope don't need to use a library. Do you have a function or has another stack question you've seen answered this?

Comment: I posted an answer below. Hopefully that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really simple countdown function I wrote a while back. Feel free to use it however.

```js
var t = new Date(2014,11,25,9,30),
    p = document.getElementById("time"),
    timer;
var u = function () {
    var delta = t - new Date(),
        d = delta / (24 * 3600 * 1000) | 0,
        h = (delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000) / (3600 * 1000) | 0,
        m = (delta %= 3600 * 1000) / (60 * 1000) | 0,
        s = (delta %= 60 * 1000) / 1000 | 0;
    
    if (delta < 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        p.innerHTML = "timer's finished!";
    } else {
        p.innerHTML = d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s";
    }
}
timer = setInterval(u, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="time"></h1>
```

The only tricky part might be my use of

```
h = (delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000) / (3600 * 1000) | 0
```

`delta %= ...` returns `delta`, after performing the `%=`. This was just to save characters. If you don't like this, you can just separate the `delta %= ...` part:

```
delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000;
h = delta / (3600 * 1000) | 0;
// ... do the same for the rest
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/h6m6u8a5/)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for that. Handy one to have in the snippet kit