# Website Countdown js

Tags: javascript

Hi I am having a hard time making this countdown work for me. I am trying to make it count down to every sunday at 11:15am since that is when our church service starts. Can anyone pleaes help me? I have the code here.

---

```
function croAnim(){ 

    // IF THERE'S A COUNTDOWN
    if ($('ul.cro_timervalue').length !== 0) {


        // GET ALL THE INSTANCES OF THE TIMER
        $('ul.cro_timervalue').each(function() {

            var $this       = $(this),
                timesets    = $this.data('cro-countdownvalue'),               
                now         = new Date(),
                tset        = Math.floor(now / 1000),
                counter1    = timesets - tset;


            // CALCULATE SECONDS
            var seconds1    = Math.floor(counter1 % 60);  
                seconds1    = (seconds1 < 10 && seconds1 >= 0) ? '0'+ seconds1 : seconds1;


            // CALCULATE MINUTES                
            counter1        =counter1/60;
            var minutes1    =Math.floor(counter1 % 60);
            minutes1        = (minutes1 < 10 && minutes1 >= 0) ? '0'+ minutes1 : minutes1;


            // CALCULATE HOURS
            counter1=counter1/60;
            var hours1=Math.floor(counter1 % 24);
            hours1 = (hours1 < 10 && hours1 >= 0) ? '0'+ hours1 : hours1;


            // CALCULATE DAYS
            counter1    =counter1/24;
            var days1   =Math.floor(counter1);
            days1       = (days1 < 10 && days1 >= 0) ? '0'+ days1 : days1;



            // ADD THE VALUES TO THE CORRECT DIVS
            $this.find('span.secondnumber').html(seconds1);
            $this.find('span.minutenumber').html(minutes1);
            $this.find('span.hournumber').html(hours1);
            $this.find('span.daynumber').html(days1); 


        });
    }
}


// CREATE A INTERVAL FOR THE TIMER
croInit = setInterval(croAnim, 100);
```

Comment: I answered your question below. However, I wanted to point out that `croInit = setInterval(croAnim, 100);` runs 10x more often than it has to. There are `1000ms` per second, so your interval should run every 1000, not 100, ms. (Unless you want to run it 10 times per second, which seems wasteful—at least you're not wasting *your* electricity, I guess)

Answer (score 1):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769790/countdownjs-how-to-show-0-units/26769881#26769881) about a week or so ago. I have a really simple countdown function already written. The trick is to modify it to get the next `Sunday @ 11:15 am`, which I've written a function for.

```js
var getNextSunday = function () {
    var today = new Date(),
        day = today.getDay(), // 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc.
        delta = 7 - day;

    var sunday = new Date(today.getTime() + (delta * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

    sunday.setHours(11);
    sunday.setMinutes(15);
    sunday.setSeconds(0);

    return sunday;
}

var t = getNextSunday(),
    p = document.getElementById("time"),
    timer;
var u = function () {
    var delta = t - new Date(),
        d = delta / (24 * 3600 * 1000) | 0,
        h = (delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000) / (3600 * 1000) | 0,
        m = (delta %= 3600 * 1000) / (60 * 1000) | 0,
        s = (delta %= 60 * 1000) / 1000 | 0;
    
    if (delta < 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        p.innerHTML = "timer's finished!";
    } else {
        p.innerHTML = d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s";
    }
}
timer = setInterval(u, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="time"></h1>
```

This should be easy enough to adapt to fit your website's needs. The only tricky part might be my use of

```
h = (delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000) / (3600 * 1000) | 0
```

`delta %= ...` returns `delta`, after performing the `%=`. This was just to save characters. If you don't like this, you can just separate the `delta %= ...` part:

```
delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000;
h = delta / (3600 * 1000) | 0;
// ... do the same for the rest
```

Comment: While it likely would not matter in this case ... setInterval() is evil :P

Comment: @Burdock `setTimeout` is really no different, especially with how you're using it.

Comment: @yoyhowie Sadly old Internet Explorers will throw errors with `Date` in some cases. `setInterval` will be more then happy to call the erring function till the end of time and bog down the browser.

Comment: That being said : I quite like your answer XD - Its always cool to see how others implement things differently.

Answer (score 0):

This object uses a few semi-advanced javascript ideas (*closures* and * IIFE*) so hopefully it is easy-ish to understand. If you have any questions feel free to leave a comment.

```
var churchtime = (function (){
    // Total seconds passed in the week by sunday 11:15am
            var magic_number = 558900;
    var now;
    var rawtime = function (){
          //updates now with the current date and time
          now = new Date()
          //Converts now into pure seconds  
          return (((((((now.getDay()-1)*24)+now.getHours())*60)+now.getMinutes())*60)+now.getSeconds());
    };

    //closure
    return {

        raw_countdown : function (){
            return Math.abs(rawtime()-magic_number);
        },

        countdown : function(){      
            var time = Math.abs(rawtime()-magic_number)  
            var seconds = time % 60, time = (time - seconds)/60; 
            var minutes = time % 60, time = (time - minutes)/60; 
            var hours = time % 24, time = (time - hours)/24;
            var days = time;
            return [days,hours,minutes,seconds];
        }
    }

})(558900); //<- Total seconds passed in the week by sunday 11:15am


churchtime.raw_countdown()// returns the raw number of seconds until church 

churchtime.countdown() // returns an array of time until church [days,hours,minutes,seconds]
```

Once you have an object like churchtime, it should be super easy to implement.

For example:

```js
var churchtime = (function(magic_number) {
  var now;
  var rawtime = function() {
    //updates now with the current date and time
    now = new Date()
      //Converts now into pure seconds  
    return (((((((now.getDay() - 1) * 24) + now.getHours()) * 60) + now.getMinutes()) * 60) + now.getSeconds());
  };

  //closure
  return {

    raw_countdown: function() {
      return Math.abs(rawtime() - magic_number);
    },

    countdown: function() {
      var time = Math.abs(rawtime() - magic_number)
      var seconds = time % 60,
        time = (time - seconds) / 60;
      var minutes = time % 60,
        time = (time - minutes) / 60;
      var hours = time % 24,
        time = (time - hours) / 24;
      var days = time;
      return [days, hours, minutes, seconds];
    }
  }

})(); //<- IIFE


AutoUpdate = function AutoUpdate() {
  var time = churchtime.countdown();
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = time[0];
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = time[1];
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = time[2];
  document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = time[3];
  setTimeout(AutoUpdate, 900); //Calls it's self again after .9 seconds
}(); //<- IIFE
```

```html
<h1>Day:<span id="day"></span> Hour:<span id="hour"></span>
Minute:<span id="min"></span> second: <span id="sec"></span></h1>
```

Comment: You probably meant to write `setTimeout(Update, 900)`. You want to pass the function to the timeout, not what it returns.

Comment: Yep, thanks I didn't catch that. Coding at 12:00 is not always the best idea :P