# How To Make This Countdown Work For Monday, Tuesday and others

Tags: javascript

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922766/website-countdown-js) someone (royhowie) shared a js that counts to every sunday. This code works well but when I try to make it work for days beyond today (current day), like tuesday, monday by changing delta value from 7 to 2 or 1, this show Timer's Finished. How to make it work?

```js
var getNextSunday = function () {
    var today = new Date(),
        day = today.getDay(), // 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc.
        delta = 7 - day;

    var sunday = new Date(today.getTime() + (delta * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

    sunday.setHours(11);
    sunday.setMinutes(15);
    sunday.setSeconds(0);

    return sunday;
}

var t = getNextSunday(),
    p = document.getElementById("time"),
    timer;
var u = function () {
    var delta = t - new Date(),
        d = delta / (24 * 3600 * 1000) | 0,
        h = (delta %= 24 * 3600 * 1000) / (3600 * 1000) | 0,
        m = (delta %= 3600 * 1000) / (60 * 1000) | 0,
        s = (delta %= 60 * 1000) / 1000 | 0;
    
    if (delta < 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        p.innerHTML = "timer's finished!";
    } else {
        p.innerHTML = d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s";
    }
}
timer = setInterval(u, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="time"></h1>
```

## Solved

@Reti43 Gentleman you are genius. Lots of respect for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply change `delta = 7 - day;` to

```
delta = (8 - day) % 7;
```

**Explanation**

Monday has the value 1, but this would be similar to 1+7.

After calculating the difference between 8 and today's date, use the modulo to get a remainder between 0 and 6.

**Example**

Today is Sunday: (8 - 0) % 7 = 8 % 7 = 1, i.e., Monday is 1 day away.

Today is Monday: (8 - 1) % 7 = 7 % 7 = 0, i.e., Monday is 0 days away.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the number 7 you want to change, its the value assigned to day:

Existing code:

```
day = today.getDay(),   // 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc.
```

You want:

```
day = 2,    // 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc.
```

Comment: That will add 2 extra days from today's date. You want to find the delta of today to the next Monday.

Comment: I just picked 2 as an example. He wants to be able to make it work for any day. So if 2 represents Tuesday, there will be 7 - 2 = 5 days until Sunday.

Comment: by changing day = today.getDay(),   // 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc. to day = 7,   // 1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed, etc. or to 6 or to 4 its giving wrong answers. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9wzw584/)

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. The OP still wants to calculate a delta, so you need to find the day difference of today to the next Monday.

Comment: The way I read the question, he wants to calculate from say next Tuesday to next Sunday. OP, can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: yes of course. I have seven pages (monday, tuesday,.. sunday). Each page has its own seperate countdown. So, the countdown which is for sunday that i shared in my main question, i want to customize it for tuesday, wednesday, and all others day.

Answer (score 0):

that's a tricky question.

Instead of decrease the "7" you have to add to it:

```
var getNextWeekday = function (nextDesirefWeekDay) { 
    var today = new Date(), 
    day = today.getDay(),   
    delta = 7 - day + nextDesirefWeekDay;
    ...
```

}

Then, in nextDesirefWeekDay you pass your desired day:

0: Sunday
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
...

I hope that helps.